# How to update values for each columns of row from modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have an HTML code like this:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div style="margin-top: 50px;">
        <table class="table table-hover" style="width: 100%;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>0</th>
                    <td class="cTenSanPham">Samsung Galaxy Note 8</td>
                    <td class="cGiaSanPham">23.000.000 VND</td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" onclick="editProductModal()">Chỉnh sửa</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-row-tb">Xóa</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

In modal code

```
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>
                                <h5 class="">Mã sản phẩm</h5>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="iMaSanPham" name="nMaSanPham" readonly>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>
                                <h5 class="">Tên sản phẩm</h5>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="iTenSanPham" name="nTenSanPham">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>
                                <h5 class="">Giá sản phẩm</h5>
                            </label>
                            <input type="number" min="500" max="999999999" class="form-control" id="iGiaSanPham"
                                name="nGiaSanPham">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

And an Javascript code like this:

```
function editProductModal() {
$(document).on("click", ".edit", function () {
    $(this).parents("tr").find("th").each(function () {
        document.getElementById("iMaSanPham").value = $(this).text();
    });

    $(this).parents("tr").find(".cTenSanPham").each(function () {
        document.getElementById("iTenSanPham").value = $(this).text();
    });

    $(this).parents("tr").find(".cGiaSanPham").each(function () {
        document.getElementById("iGiaSanPham").value = parseInt($(this).text().replace(/\D/g, ''));
    });
});
```

}

I want when I click the button '**Chỉnh sửa**' on any row, a **modal** will open and fill data from this row into this **modal** ***(the modal of bootstrap 4)***. I can edit on this modal, then I press a button to pass updated data to table. How to do it in **function editProductModal()** in file JS. Thank you so much

Comment: Hi. Please read [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you improve the level of detail in your question. Please can you include the source code in your post, not externally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var $currentEditRow;

$(document).on("click", ".edit", function() {
  $currentEditRow = $(this).parents("tr");
  editProductModal($(this).parents("tr"));
});

function editProductModal(row) {
  document.getElementById("iMaSanPham").value = $(row).find("th").text();

  document.getElementById("iTenSanPham").value = $(row).find(".cTenSanPham").text();

  document.getElementById("iGiaSanPham").value = parseInt($(row).find(".cGiaSanPham").text().replace(/\D/g, ''));
}

function update() {
  $currentEditRow.find("th").text(document.getElementById("iMaSanPham").value);

  $currentEditRow.find(".cTenSanPham").text(document.getElementById("iTenSanPham").value);
  $currentEditRow.find(".cGiaSanPham").text(document.getElementById("iGiaSanPham").value);

  $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <table class="table table-hover" style="width: 100%;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>0</th>
          <td class="cTenSanPham">Samsung Galaxy Note 8</td>
          <td class="cGiaSanPham">23.000.000 VND</td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" onclick="editProductModal()">Chỉnh sửa</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-row-tb">Xóa</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>
                                <h5 class="">Mã sản phẩm</h5>
                            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="iMaSanPham" name="nMaSanPham" readonly>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>
                                <h5 class="">Tên sản phẩm</h5>
                            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="iTenSanPham" name="nTenSanPham">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>
                                <h5 class="">Giá sản phẩm</h5>
                            </label>
            <input type="number" min="500" max="999999999" class="form-control" id="iGiaSanPham" name="nGiaSanPham">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="update()">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When editing the current `tr` row, store the dom of the current row, so you can determine which line to update to in the modal.

You can try to update the row data in my code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You are improperly mixing inline `onclick` and jQuery click event listeners together.

Remove the function and the `onclick` and just use the jQuery code inside the function  by itself  to manage the event

You also don't need an `each` loop to access the elements within the row.

---

Simplified version:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".edit", function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
    thText = $row.find('th').text(),
    cTenSanPham = $row.find('.cTenSanPham').text(),
    cGiaSanPham = $('.cGiaSanPham').text().replace(/\D/g, '');

  $('#iMaSanPham').val(thText);
  $('#iTenSanPham').val(cTenSanPham);
  $('#iGiaSanPham').val(cGiaSanPham);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <table class="table table-hover" style="width: 100%;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>0</th>
          <td class="cTenSanPham">Samsung Galaxy Note 8</td>
          <td class="cGiaSanPham">23.000.000 VND</td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Chỉnh sửa</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-row-tb">Xóa</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>66</th>
          <td class="cTenSanPham">Another Item</td>
          <td class="cGiaSanPham">99.000.000 VND</td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Chỉnh sửa</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-row-tb">Xóa</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<h3>Modal</h3>

<div class="modal-body">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>
                                <h5 class="">Mã sản phẩm</h5>
                            </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="iMaSanPham" name="nMaSanPham" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>
                                <h5 class="">Tên sản phẩm</h5>
                            </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="iTenSanPham" name="nTenSanPham">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>
                                <h5 class="">Giá sản phẩm</h5>
                            </label>
      <input type="number" min="500" max="999999999" class="form-control" id="iGiaSanPham" name="nGiaSanPham">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```